# Setting frame of a UITableView to match its content size

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a non scrolling UITableView inside of a larger UIScrollView. Since the table view is non scrolling, I want its frame size to always match its content size.

I have the following method that I call:

```
- (void)resizeTableViewFrameHeight
{
    // Table view does not scroll, so its frame height should be equal to its contentSize height
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size = self.tableView.contentSize;
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
}
```

The problem is that I must be calling this method at the wrong time (before the contentSize is set). I was wondering, is there a property that I can set on UITableView that will cause its frame to always match its content size automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property that dynamically adjusts table view's frame. Also, I do not think that a `UITableView` can calculate its entire `contentSize` up-front because a table view could be practically infinite in size, depending what is specified from its `datasource` and other delegate methods such as `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. These methods can be dynamic, making it virtually impossible to predict the entire size of a table view.

I conclude that you are perhaps not using this UI element correctly.

**Workaround:**

By having the frame of the table view constrained to the visible area of the scroll view you could simply allow it to scroll. Perhaps you need to prevent your scroll view from scrolling while the table view is scrolling and vice versa. You could easily do this in the `UIScrollView` delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I cannot have my table view scrolling, it doesn't make sense for my UI. But I guess I'll just have to resize its frame myself.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something like this in iOS 8: A scroll view that contained a non-scrolling fixed-width table view with variable number of rows of content, so I wanted to dynamically resize the height of the table view.

What worked for me was to set up a height constraint on the table view with a dummy value, and then create outlets to both the table view and the constraint. Then this was all I needed:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    }

    // (plus additional data source methods, etc.)
}
```

I can imagine situations (maybe with lots of rows, or rows of variable height) where it might not be this simple, but this worked for me.